# Is Young's inequality true without the continuity assumption?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing function, $f(0) =0$, 
$a>0$ and $b>0$, then $\int^a_0 f+ \int^b_0 f^{−1} ≥ ab$. Is this true without continuity assumed?

Comment: $f^{-1}$ may not be defined on $(0,b)$ if $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But the generalized inverse is still defined and I think it's true with that one.

Comment: What do you mean be generalized inverse?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible generalization. If $f$ is right-continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}=\infty$, then
$$
\bbox[cornsilk,5px]
{
\int_0^a f(x)\,dx + \int_0^b f^{-}(y)\,dy\ge ab
}
$$
for all $a,b\ge 0$, where
$$
f^{-}(y):=\sup\{x\ge 0:f(x)\le y\}
$$
is the *generalized inverse* of $f$.

---

To see this, define
\begin{align}
A&:=\{(x,y):x\in[0,a],y\in[0,b]\},\\[5pt]
B&:=\{(x,y):x\in[0,a],y\in[0,f(x)]\}, \quad\text{and}\\[5pt]
C&:=\{(x,y):y\in[0,b],x\in[0,f^{-}(y)]\}.
\end{align}
Then, since $A\subseteq B\cup C$,
$$
m(A)\le m(B)+m(C),
$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (note that $A, B$, and $C$ are measurable sets).